# foreach loop for number of arrays

Tags: php, foreach, foreach-loop-container

Code:

```
foreach ($output as $result)
print_r($result);
```

Below is the output of my above code:

```
Array ( [0] => 323 [1] => 323 [2] => 323 [3] => 323 [4] => 65 [5] => 65 [6] => 65 [7] => 65 [8] => 121 [9] => 121 [10] => 121 [11] => 121 ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( [0] => 656 [1] => 656 [2] => 656 [3] => 656 ) 
Array ( [0] => 777 [1] => 777 [2] => 777 [3] => 777 ) 
Array ( [0] => 321 [1] => 321 [2] => 321 [3] => 321 [4] => 434 [5] => 434 [6] => 434 [7] => 434 [8] => 400 [9] => 400 [10] => 400 [11] => 400 ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( [0] => 300 [1] => 300 [2] => 300 [3] => 300 [4] => 666 [5] => 666 [6] => 666 [7] => 666 ) 
Array ( )
Array ( [0] => 167 [1] => 167 [2] => 167 [3] => 167 )
```

I want to print each array separately. Trying nested `foreach` loop but not getting required output.

Please help

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: What you mean by separately ? Can you show us your expected output ?

Comment: I don't see a problem here. The arrays are printed separately in my eyes.

Comment: They are separated if you want to be with better display put one: echo "<pre>"; before your foreach..

Comment: I want to print each array separately, like here i have 11 arrays seen from the output

Comment: @sidd they are separated (each in new line..) this is the normal standard..

Answer (score 0):

Nested loop would be simple

```
foreach ($output as $outer)
{
  foreach ($outer as $inner)
  {
    print_r($inner);
  }
}
```